# Fresnel Integral and his formulas

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, integration

Below is how Fresnel approximate the eponymously "Fresnel Integral". In his own words:

*Let $i$ and $i+t$ be the narrow limits between which it is proposed to integrate  $\cos(qv^2) \, dv$. Neglecting the square of $t/2$ we then find the following approximate value for the integral.* 
$$\int \cos(qv^2) \, dv = \frac{1}{2q(i+\frac{t}2)}(\sin[q(i+\frac{t}2)(i+\frac{3t}2)]-(\sin[q(i+\frac{t}2)(i-\frac{t}2)] $$
 *This is the formula which I have used in the computation of the table:*

HERE IS THE TABLE: https://archive.org/stream/wavetheoryofligh00crewrich#page/122

Also in the previous page of the table there is a note on how Fresnel compute the integral.

My question is, what are the $i$ and $t$ values which he takes in order to compute the whole table? I tried with $i=0$,$t=0.1, 0.2...$ but no success for all the values of the table.